# How to format a cloned datepicker to only display a year only

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a field that requires the user to select year only from a datepicker.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKodi.png)

The picture above displays it correctly. But when I cloned the fields the year picker now displays the datepicker which displays the day, month and year format. Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH9Ni.png)

How can I set it back in displaying the year picker in the cloned fields?  This is my jquery for cloning the fields.

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {

     var newRow = $("#collegeField").clone();

     $('.yrpicker').datepicker

     $("#collegebtn").on("click", function() {

       newRow.clone().appendTo("#collegeField").find(".yrpicker").datepicker();
     });

   });
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
<label for="college_school">Started</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker yrpicker" name="yrStarted" id="yrStarted" placeholder="From">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-1">
<label for="college_school">Graduated</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker yrpicker" name="yrGrad" id="yrStop" placeholder="To">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right it won't work for your case. I looked around in jquery date picker docs, and I don't think there is anything to do what you're looking for.

Comment: yeah, i've been looking for answers too but still did't find anything. Thanks anyway. :D